# htaccess files: Changing URL to username

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In the following thread:

[How to create user profiles with PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180779/how-to-create-user-profiles-with-php-and-mysql)

I have a number of doubts:

1. In the first answer (by Chacha102) what is the '$1', I understand that it refers to a paramter but which one?
2. Does not the code in the first answer redirect to another index.php without renaming the url to something like www.facebook.com/username?

UPDATE:

Where does the edit to the url occur?

Answer (score 1):

**Doubt 1:**
It refers to value of a get parameter user. For instance, if you have `index.php?user=Name` it refers to "Name".

**Doubt 2:**
The code wouldn't redirect. It will just rewrite url to `www.domain.com/Name`. It's equivalent to `www.domain.com/index.php?user=Name`.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast!! For the first doubt: where is the get parameter received from? and for the second doubt: if I want to build my own profile system do I need to create multiple files for multiple users or create one file and rename the url after populating it with the user data?

Comment: It's recieved from url. What you want to do is to create dynamic page with php with sql database with users. Then you just change url to match with user.

Answer (score 1):

**1:** The `$1` is called the first captured group from the pattern. It refers to the value `?user=`**john** 
([Read more about capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html))

**2:** In most of the PHP application the main entry (routing) point of http request is `index.php`. If you enter the url like `http://www.example.com/john` actually it would be the same as `http://www.example.com/index.php?user=john` if you have applied the same mod_rewrite rule from the answer.

Comment: thanks for the comment, therefore are .htaccess files read everytime someone requests ANY page which is services by that .htaccess file?Suppose I needed to access a completely different page which was located in a subdirectory to the .htaccess file, will the server then direct the request to the .htaccess file first?

Comment: Yes every request will first handshake with the `.htaccess` root file before shaking hands with application files.