# display username in url instead of id using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have already look for this [How to create user profiles with PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180779/how-to-create-user-profiles-with-php-and-mysql) and this [profile username in URL instead of user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182896/profile-username-in-url-instead-of-user-id) and the others as well. but it is still not working for me. My current `url` when the user view his/her profile is like this `http://localhost/sn/profile.php?id=1` now what i want for the `url` is to be like this `http://localhost/sn/myusername` i know this is maybe a duplicate but still any answer didn't work for me so far :( any help please? Thanks in advance.

This is what i have tried in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://localhost/sn/profile.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Where is located your htaccess ? In your `sn` directory or in document root directory ?

Comment: it is located inside the `sn` folder together with my `index.php` and `profile.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htaccess code should be as follow:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Note that you have to change logic in `profile.php` to get user by **username** (and not by ID anymore)

Comment: what do you mean by that sir?

Comment: An example: you want to reach `http://localhost/sn/Pengun` which is internally redirected to `profile.php?id=Pengun`. Before, your php page was receiving ID but now it is username