# PHP/mysql - How to pass variables from class to separate index.php? Profile pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new to PHP and trying to figure this out- right now on one page I have a search form that creates a div on the page for any users that meet what was entered in the form here:

```
echo '<form class="usersearch" method="post"><input class="searchbar" name="searchbar"></input><input type="submit" class="submitsearch" value="search" name="submitsearch"></input></form>"';
if(isset($_POST['submitsearch']) || isset($_POST['searchbar'])){
$sess->getUsers();
echo '</div>';
```

When the user presses enter `getUsers()` is called from a separate class called Session. The getUsers() func creates divs and displays data from a mysql table:

```
public function getUsers()
    {
        echo '<div class="results">';
        $query = $_POST['searchbar'];
        $sql = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","sqlserver");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM sqlserver.accounts WHERE username LIKE '%".$query."%'";
        $query = $sql->query($query);
        $sql->close();
        while($user = $query->fetch_assoc())
        {

            echo '<a class = "result" href = "../profile">'.$user['username'].' '.$user['blurb'].'</a><br>'; //fix css

        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Because the search creates all these a hrefs on the page, when the user clicks one right now it sends them to the index.php in my profile page folder.

My issue with these links is that I need to "send" for lack of better wording the username that displayed in the a href that was clicked to my index.php in my profile folder so I can echo back the appropriate data corresponding with this username from my mysql table. I am unsure as to the best way to accomplish this

Is there any way to do this using a href? Or should I just use a div and use Javascript/ajax to pass the username variable displayed in the div to index.php in profile? How can I do this?

Comment: PS: You don't need to echo html. You can close your tag and reopen it. Like so: <?php if($variable === true){ ?> <div> html here </div> <?php } ?>

Comment: Have you tried this ` href = "../profile?user='.$user['username'].'" ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you're looking to use query strings?

It's kinda like post, but you can see the parameters in the url. [Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

You might want to look into the php function [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to parse the query string for you.